# Threading a random number generator function in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following code in python:

```
results=[]
for i in range(1,7000000):
    a=(random.sample(range(1, 45), 6))
    results.append(a)
```

Is there a way I can use threading or any other method to make this code run faster? At the moment its just taking forever,over 20 minutes.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? On either one, calling `range(1, 45)` over and over would add non-trivial overhead; creating it outside the loop would likely help (especially on Py2 where recreating it over and over involves making 44 element lists over and over, not just the virtual sequence used on Py3). Threading probably won't get you much of anything, given the GIL, and multiprocessing would likely spend as much time transferring values from workers to the parent process as it saved in parallelism. You might consider using `numpy`; it could generate a 2D array of random quite quickly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger i'm using python 3.6. How do i call the range outside the loop though as I need it to repeat 7000000 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a lot to be gained from threading here, thanks to [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), but this is a problem that can be solved with `numpy`, which can perform the work entirely at the C layer, saving a ton of time and memory to boot. A 7M by 6 sized 2D array with values in the given range can be created in less than a second with:

```
import numpy as np

results = np.random.randint(1, 45, (7000000, 6), np.uint8)
```

This going to be faster in general, and much more memory efficient; a 7M long `list` of six-`tuple`s will (on a 64 bit version of Python) occupy an absolute minimum of around 700 MB (likely more, given allocator overhead). The `numpy` array will occupy about 40 MB. It's also pretty easy to show that the creation of this `list` with all the inner `tuple`s has unavoidable costs; microbenchmarking the `numpy` array alone shows that all the random number generation only takes around 420 ms, but converting from the `numpy` array to a `list` of six-`tuple`s in the most efficient way brings the cost up to 12.5 seconds; if your machine is similar to mine, that's essentially a cap on the performance of *any* pure Python solution, because it's the raw cost paid by Python to create the `tuple`s and populate the `list`:

```
>>> %timeit -r5 arr = np.random.randint(1, 45, (7000000, 6), np.uint8)
420 ms ± 875 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit -r5 arr = list(map(tuple, np.random.randint(1, 45, (7000000, 6), np.uint8)))
12.5 s ± 254 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`np.random.randint(1, 45, (7000000, 6), np.uint8).tolist()` goes faster the `list(map(tuple, ...))` (takes around 2.5 seconds), but again, that's only possible because of the C level accelerator assistance (and it would use even more memory, thanks to `list`s being somewhat less memory efficient).

Without `numpy`, the best I can suggest is to avoiding recreating the `range` over and over, by creating it once outside the loop and reusing it, e.g.:

```
choices = tuple(range(1, 45))  # tuple is generally the fastest structure to index
results = []
for i in range(1, 7000000):
    a = random.sample(choices, 6)
    results.append(a)
```

That's not likely to save a whole lot though; the `random` module does an awful lot of Python level work wrapping 1-2 C level randomness generators, and that Python level work is going to be *much* slower than anything a fully accelerated C module could do.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot, got results in seconds using numpy. Is there a built-in way to ensure the results dont repeat or i have to code for that separately?

Comment: @West: I'm sure there is a way, but I'll admit to having limited experience with `numpy` for this purpose; I can't find any obvious way to do it.

Comment: Ok will look into it. Cheers

Comment: Avoiding repeats is going to be _very_ cpu intensive.  Your best bet is likely to put all your results in a hashset, see how many collisions you have and then redo however many you need in pure python code again, checking for collisions as you go.

Comment: Especially if ordering matters (i.e. if `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) == (6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)`) then you will have a lot of collisions.

Comment: @Turksarama Sure. For example if I needed all 3 number combinations in range(1,5) I will get (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4). I have just found out if I wanted no repeats I can do the above with: `for c in combinations(range(45),6):
        d.append(c)` where d is an empty list. Takes about 5 seconds not sure if its the fastest way though

Comment: I downvoted because this solution draws 7000000*6 independent samples and puts them in an arrya, which is not the same as drawing 7000000 samples of 6 numbers drawn from the given range (a sample of 6 will have no repeats)

Answer (score 0):

[mtalg](https://github.com/WWakker/mtalg) implements multithreaded random number generation, although in this case the overhead plays a big role since we are talking about milliseconds, but speed-ups are larger for larger arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import mtalg
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)
mrng = mtalg.random.MultithreadedRNG(seed=1, num_threads=8)

%timeit -r5 rng.integers(1, 45, (7000000, 6), np.uint8)
# 211 ms ± 2.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -r5 mrng.integers(1, 45, (7000000, 6), np.uint8)
# 179 ms ± 3.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10 loops each)
```